# change user in linux script

Tags: linux, sh

User x run a script. Now I want to change the user in the script to User y.

```
#!/bin/sh
whoami
echo password | su y
whoami
```

But I get this:

```
x
su: must be run from a terminal
x
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 14):

This is working for me inside a bash script:

```
whoami;
sudo su $user << BASH
  whoami;
BASH
```

Comment: Only works where sudo is available. Debian has no sudo command.

Answer (score 5):

Su cannot be ran in a Bash script. You can use `sudo -u <user> <command> &&` however.

Comment: Not entirely true. It is possible to run su from a script as long as you give it a terminal. For example:`ssh -t user@localhost "su -c whoami"`

Answer (score -2):

you can do:

su - $USER -l -m -c $CMD

-l provide an environment similar to the login env
-m preserves the current environment
-c runs the command

e.g. I use this to run nohup commands also

su - $USER -l -m -c "nohup $RUN_CMD > "$LOG" 2>&1 >> /dev/null&"